# A shorter way to list all packages matching a string

Tags: bash, grep, dpkg, cut

When I search for a list of packages, I usually use

```
dpkg -l|grep string|cut -d" " -f3|xargs
```

> libdouble-conversion3:amd64 libestr0:amd64 libeval-closure-perl
> libio-stringy-perl libunistring2:amd64 liburi-perl libustr-1.0-1:amd64
> libwind0-heimdal:amd64 libxstring-perl php-mbstring php7.0-mbstring
> php7.4-mbstring php8.2-mbstring

is there a shorter way in bash to get this list?

Comment: If you want just the list, remove `xargs`, that just puts everything on a single line.

Comment: `dpkg -l` seems to be truncating package names that don't fit into the column.

Comment: Otherwise `dpkg -l | awk '{ print $2 }'` is nicer than mucking around with cut. It looks like packages don't contain spaces, and even when the names are truncated to fit the column, they do not touch the next column.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`dpkg-query` allows formatting the output, when using `-W` instead of `-l`.

E.g.

```
dpkg-query -f='${binary:Package} ' -W  'pyth*'
```

would list all binary packages starting with `pyth` and separate them by space, with their architecture when necessary.

More details on possible formats in `man dpkg-query`.

It might not necessarily be shorter, but you may define an alias based on it and hence just use the REGEX-query.

Comment: And this is without architecture:. ` dpkg-query -f='${Package} ' -W  binutils*`

Answer (score 4):

If you wanted to learn only *one* tool that can search packages, you could consider `aptitude` whose [search syntax](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/aptitude/ch02s04s05.en.html) is *extremely* versatile and can let you search on many criteria about installed packages or not.

Here:

```
aptitude -q search -F %p '~i ^pyth'
```

Would search packages that are installed ([`~i`, short for `?installed`](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/aptitude/ch02s04s05.en.html#searchInstalled)) and whose name matches the given regular expression (`^pyth` short for `~n^pyth` or [`?name(^pyth)`](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/aptitude/ch02s04s05.en.html#searchTermName)).

`-F %p` specifies the [output format](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/aptitude/ch02s05s01.en.html#secDisplayFormat), here with `%p` being the package name.

If you wanted to print the list space-separated on one line, `xargs` (short for `xargs echo`) is not the right tool for that. Use `paste -sd ' ' -` instead. If the point is to pass that list of packages to another command:

```
dpkg/aptitude... | xargs -rd '\n' cmd --
```

Though:

```
dpkg/aptitude... | xargs -r cmd
```

Should also work as package names generally don't start with `-` and don't contain whitespace, quotes or backslash characters which would be a problem for `xargs` without `-0`/`-d`.

If the command is that to uninstall/purge the packages, note that you can also do:

```
aptitude remove '~i ^pyth'
```

Also note that you can do the same search within the `aptitude` TUI by pressing <kbd>l</kbd> (to `l`imit the view) and enter the search specification there, preferably in a *flat list view*. Then, it makes it easier to see details of those packages and perform actions on those. The first thing I do when running `aptitude` for the first time on a system is to change the default settings in *Options* -> *Preferences* by ticking:

```
    [X] Advance to the next item after changing the state of a package
    [X] Display flat view instead of default view on startup
```

Which makes applying action on a set of filtered packages easier.